# Azure event Grid trigger function is reading all the existing files in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have Created an azure Evet Grid trigger Java function which reads blob files whenever a new file is uploaded to container.

But the problem is when I deployed the function , its reading all the existing files from container. Ideally it should get triggered only when there is a new or updated files uploaded to container.

Here is the code.

```
@FunctionName("MyEventGridTrigger")
@StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")
public void run(@EventGridTrigger(name = "eventGridTrigger") String msg,
        @BlobInput(name = "blob", dataType = "binary", path = "{data.url}") byte[] byte,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Event Grid trigger function executed.");
    
    // Logic to read file from byte[]
}
```

**Everything working fine**, but its reading the existing files.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Do you use the etags for concurrency? Do you do any filtering? I mean, your function has never handled those events after its first deployment. And you use the event grid for atleast once delivery to the function, so I think it's working as designed.

Comment: I am new to azure function so i dont know much about concurrency and etags..could you please provide some solution not to process existing files

Comment: I don't have a readyily made solution available for you. Hence me not posting an answer. Just helping out with the thinking. Do you filter the events? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage?tabs=event-grid-event-schema#list-of-events-for-blob-rest-apis So it only triggers on the BlobCreated event? The etag thought was mainly, you adding etags to your events, and then have your code only trigger when etag is > where ever you would want it to start from. As I have never worked with the Event Grid; I'm not even sure that's a practice you would want to follow..

Comment: etag property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.eventgrid.models.storageblobcreatedeventdata?view=azure-java-stable - But i honestly think if you only trigger on BlobCreated events, that would fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have also implemented same type of event grid through azure portal. I followed three steps.

1. **Create Azure Storage Topic** :- That is Event Grid System Topic
2. **Event Subscription and Filter** :- in this step, there are two main point

   a. **Event type** :- Tell when event trigger  for example create blob (when file is uploaded in blob) or delete blob.

   b. **End Point Type**:- Which subscribe the event like azure function. At this point give information about azure function.
3. **Handle Event with AzureFunction** :- Write Code for handle event or action after event fire.

Please click on this link for more help :- [Create, view, and manage Event Grid system topics in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/create-view-manage-system-topics)

By this, you can start your journey in azure and then you can figure it out that how can do by without azure portal. But for custom event grid also you need to create event grid topic.

**Note :- Before using Event Grid in azure, Need to register Event Grid Resource Provide first**

Please let me know if you still are facing issue.

Comment: Hey, whatever u  have written i have done that already. thats not my concern. my concern  is when i deploy my function it reads all the existing file which it should not ideally.